# Why does Jacobi method only converge for one of these two equivalent ways of stating a problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

Consider the system \begin{align}a=b-2\\ b=2a+14\end{align} Implementing a simple Jacobi method and initializing at $(a,b)=(0,0)$, updating by $a^{k+1}=b^{k}-2$, $b^{k+1}=2a^k+14$, we get: $(-2,14),(12,10),(8,38),(36,30),(28,86)\cdots$, and the resulting sequence does not converge.

By contrast, consider the equivalent description \begin{align}a=\frac b2 - 7\\ b=a+2\end{align} and the corresponding update rules $a^{k+1}=\frac {b^k} 2-7$, $b^{k+1}=a^k+2$. Here, the Jacobi method quickly converges to the truth, $a=-12$, $b=-10$.

What's with the difference between the two? Why does Jacobi work on the second version and not on the equivalent first version? I get that the matrix describing this system is not strictly diagonally dominant, and that therefore Jacobi is not guaranteed to converge, but I still find it surprising that it converges for only one of the above two statements of the problem.

Comment: Suppose your initial guess for $a$ is off by $1$. Then after the first iteration your guess for $b$ will be off by $2$, after the second $a$ will also be off by $2$, and after the third $b$ will be off by $4$ and so on... Diagonal dominance means the coefficients on the right should (add up to) be less than one, so you don't amplify the error on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix that defines the "original" linear equations is $$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ for unknowns $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} $ and right-hand-side $b_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 14 \end{pmatrix} $. The error propagation matrix $C$ such that
$$e^{k+1} = C e^k$$ for the Jacobi method is given by $$C = I - D^{-1} A \Rightarrow C_1 = I - IA_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix consisting of the diagonal elements of $A$. The spectral radius of $C_1$ is $\rho(C_1) = \sqrt{2} > 1$, thus convergence is not guaranteed (as observed). Now consider the second formulation with $$A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -0.5 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ with right-hand-side $b_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -7 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} $. Here, $$C_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0.5 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$ and the spectral radius is $\rho(C_2) = 1/\sqrt{2} < 1$ thus convergence is guaranteed for every starting vector.